# Getting the highest column value from csv file and storing it into arraylist

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

[image: This is the csv file i'm working on.]

I'm trying to store into arraylistONE the ***Sub Name*** of ***Name*** that has the highest ***admin*** value.

In this case,

1. **All-Purpose Flour** it is `1 3/4 cups all-purpose flour`
2. **Baking Powder** it is `1/4 teaspoon baking soda and 1/2 cup of plain`
3. **Baking Soda** it is `8 teaspoons of baking powder`

If a ***Name*** only has 0 ***admin*** values it should be,

1. ***Brewed Coffee*** it should always store the first value in the file which is `1 cup brewed coffee`

And for the rest of the data that has lesser ***admin*** value, they are stored into arraylistTWO.

I'm stuck in reading the csv file and i don't know how to store into arraylistONE the ***Sub Name*** of ***Name*** that has the highest ***admin*** value and for the rest of the data that has lesser ***admin*** value, i don't know how to store into arraylistTWO.

This is the work i've done so far:

```
try {
    br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("/sdcard/TABLE_BF.csv"));
    while ((sCurrentline = br.readLine ()) != null) {
           subIng.add(sCurrentline.split (","));
    }
    arrSubIng = new String[subIng.size ()][];
    subIng.toArray (arrSubIng);
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

Comment: You are reading two different files in your code, how is that relevant to your question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i forgot to exclude it

Comment: Is this homework with some restrictions or is it ok to use Java 8 and streams?

Comment: Is the CSV file sorted by _Name_ as per the example data you posted?

Comment: There are no restrictions. I have minSdkVersion 19 and targetSdkVersion 27 set in my project @JoakimDanielson

Comment: It is not sorted within the csv file @Abra

Comment: Can the entire contents of the file be loaded into memory? Or is it a huge file?

Comment: @Abra it's just a small file. 4 columns and 60 rows

Comment: @SophiaDeLeon: Rather than posting an image, can you post your file as *text* so that it will be easy to replicate your problem. Also I suggest using an OO approach here.

Comment: @NicholasK i'm new to this, i'll try my best to read more thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think it makes sense to create a simple class that holds the data since it will be easier to filter and sort using objects rather than arrays of values.

```
public class Ingredient {
    String name;
    String subName;
    int status;
    int admin;

    public Ingredient(String name, String subName, String status, String admin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subName = subName;
        this.status = Integer.valueOf(status);
        this.admin = Integer.valueOf(admin);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }
    //more get and set methods here. I have only included what is needed for my answer
}
```

Then you read and create a list of `Ingredient` objects.

```
List<Ingredient> data = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    String sCurrentline = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sdcard/MAIN_BF.csv"));
    while ((sCurrentline = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] arr = sCurrentline.split(",");
        Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
        data.add(ingredient);
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then we group the list by name into a `Map`

```
Map<String, List<Ingredient>> ingredientsByName = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Ingredient::getName));
```

And loop over that map to find the max admin value for each ingredient and add them to the correct list

```
List<Ingredient> main = new ArrayList<>();
List<Ingredient> other = new ArrayList<>();

//Sort on `admin` in descending order
Comparator<Ingredient> compartor = Comparator.comparing(Ingredient:: getAdmin, (i1, i2) -> {
    if (i2 > i1) {
        return -1;
    } else if (i2 < i1) {
        return 1;
    } 
    return 0;
});

//Go through each list (ingredient) and find the one with max `admin` value 
//and add it to the `main` list then add the rest to `other`
ingredientsByName.forEach( (k, group) -> {
    Ingredient max = group.stream().max(compartor).get();
    if (max.getAdmin() == 0) {
        max = group.get(0);
    }
    main.add(max);
    group.remove(max);
    other.addAll(group);
});
```

Comment: hey i think it worked. but i'm still trying to print out what are the values stored in each list. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would load the entire contents of the file into memory and store it in a `java.util.List<String>`. Then you could sort the `List` by *Name* and *admin*. Then just iterate through the `List`. Whenever you hit a different *Name*, you know that its associated *admin* value is the largest. So you add that to your first `ArrayList` and all the others to your second `ArrayList`.

Comment: How do you sort the list by `Name` and `admin` when it only contain Strings, there  are no `Name` and `admin` attributes then ,is there? Please add some code to your answer explaining what you mean.